# How to validate answer by enter key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have created an input box, which gets validated by using the tab key, but it needs to be validated after pressing the enter key.

[image]

Here, the tick mark symbol is displayed only after I type the correct answer and then press tab. Then it goes to the next input box and also validation occurs.

But the validation needs to occur when I type the correct answer and hit the enter inside the input box itself.

For that I tried this JS code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    checktxt(h,v,w,c)
  }
});

function checktxt(h,v,w,c) {
  var th=$("#"+h).val();
  var tv=$("#"+v).val();
  if(th.toLowerCase()==tv.toLowerCase()) {
    $( "."+c ).show();
    $( "."+w ).hide(); 
  } else if(tv.toLowerCase()=="") {
  } else {
    $( "."+c ).hide();
    $( "."+w ).show();
  }
}
```

But also it does not get validated when I press the enter key.

And my HTML code is

```
<div>
  <input id="texthidden1" type="hidden" value="877" />
  <input id="textvisible1" type="text" value="" onblur="javascript:checktxt('texthidden1','textvisible1','wrong1','correct1');" />
  <div class="wrong1"><img src="../images/smallwrong.png"/></div>
  <div class="correct1"><img src="../images/smallgreen.png"/></div>
</div>
```

[image]

**I also need the tick image to be disappeared when i erase the content of the input box.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with you code is this part in your keypress listner

```
checktxt(h,v,w,c)
```

h,v,w and c are undefined here, since the code for onblur events working fine and you want to replicate the same on enter press, you need to defined these variable in you keypress event.

If you check your html , you are passing the ids of all elements to to checktxt function in your JS.

Do the same inside keypress listener as well.

```
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
    checktxt('texthidden1','textvisible1','wrong1','correct1')
    }
 });
```

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    checktxt('texthidden1', 'textvisible1', 'wrong1', 'correct1')
  }
});

function checktxt(h, v, w, c) {
  var th = $("#" + h).val();
  var tv = $("#" + v).val();
  if (th.toLowerCase() == tv.toLowerCase()) {
    $("." + c).show();
    $("." + w).hide();
  } else if (tv.toLowerCase() == "") {} else {
    $("." + c).hide();
    $("." + w).show();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="texthidden1" type="hidden" value="877" />
  <input id="textvisible1" type="text" value="" onblur="javascript:checktxt('texthidden1','textvisible1','wrong1','correct1');" />
  <div class="wrong1">
    <img src="../images/smallwrong.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="correct1">
    <img src="../images/smallgreen.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also need the tick image to be disappeared when i erase the content of the input box.

Comment: @Anitha you can bind a change event listener on the input and check if the value is empty.